# Gmail Integration

Tags: lightning

Gmail integration is turned on and Lightning for Gmail is installed.

When an email get sent, it will be related to the selected Account and Contacts, however, when the customer made a reply and receive in Rep's gmail, that email doesn't auto-relate to the previously selected Account.

Any configuration which I am missing here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Salesforce have an object called InboundEmail that stores incoming email contents and attachment. You can configure everything using email services.